# getting the value of line item entity field in CommerceLicenseRemoteBase class

Tags: 7, commerce, hooks

I am extending CommerceLicenseRemoteBase class for remote synchronization. I have added a custom line item and require that value in

```
CommerceLicenseSynchronizableInterface::synchronize().
```

How can i fetch the value of custom line item. I have tried

```
$license = entity_load_single('commerce_license', $id);
entity_metadata_wrapper('commerce_license', $license)
```

but that did not work.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Generally you'd do something like this:

```
$wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('commerce_license', $license);
$wrapper->PROPERTY_YOU_WANT->value();
```

(See here for more detail: https://www.drupal.org/documentation/entity-metadata-wrappers)

You could always ask in the issue queue for the module:

https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/commerce_license?categories=All

Comment: that will not work because commerce_license does not have reference to line item entity type, it will throw a PDOException of no property found. The commerce_line_item entity references commerce_license.

Answer (score 0):

entity_metadata_wrapper 
did not work because commerce_license was not referencing commerce_line_item entity, it was the other way around. I got it working by querying the commerce_line_item entity with commerce_lincese condition and then called commerce_line_item_load on the line_item_id, here is the code i used.

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
$query
  ->entityCondition('entity_type', 'commerce_line_item')
  ->fieldCondition('commerce_license', 'target_id', $license_id);
$results = $query->execute();

dpm($results);
dpm(commerce_line_item_load($line_item_id));
```

Please let me know if there are any other way to get the line_item id from license_id.

Thank you